# Unbounded symmetric convex sets

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, normed-spaces

If $X$ is a normed space, can one find a open, unbounded, symmetric, convex set $C$ that is bounded in every direction? That is, for every $x \neq 0$ there exists $\lambda_x>0$ such that for any $|\lambda|>\lambda_x$, $\lambda x\notin C$?

Comment: No. In a locally convex space a set if bounded **iff** it is weakly bounded.

Comment: @copper.hat Not sure I understand. Take, in $\mathbb{R}^2$,  $C$ to be the union of segments joining the origin with the point $(n,1)$, for any $n$. Then $C$ is unbounded, but is bounded in every direction. Convexity has to play a role, I think the condition in the statement is weaker than weak boundedness.

Comment: What do you mean by bounded in every direction? The set you described is unbounded in the $e_2$ direction?

Comment: @copper.hat For natural, non-zero $n$, the $e_2$ direction is not in $C$ at all.  By bounded in any direction I mean the set contains no infinite line through the origin. Doesn't the condition I wrote mean that?

Comment: Ahh....this is easy, just take a band along $e_1$. All the points $(x,y)$ with $-1<y<1$ and $x\in\mathbb{R}$. It satisfies all the conditions. I made it more complicated than it is.

Comment: The word direction has different meanings in different contexts. In context I would take it as any linear functional. Another meaning is direction of recession (for a convex set) and the set you describe has a direction of recession which is all translates of the ray $\{ t e_2 \}_{ t \ge 0 }$. (Presumably you mean half line or ray through the origin.)

Comment: @Markus Your example is unbounded in $e_1 $direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X = \ell^1$, i.e. the set of infinite sequences $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$ with the norm $\|x\| = \sum_n |x_n|$. Take $C$ to be all sequences for which $\sup_n |x_n| < 1$.

- $C$ is **open** because if $x = (x_n) \in C$, then $\sup_n |x_n| = s < 1$. For any $y = (y_n) \in X$ such that $\|y\| < \frac {1-s} 2$, we have: $|y_n| \le \sum_n |y_n| < \frac {1-s} 2$, hence $|x_n + y_n| \le |x_n| + |y_n| < s + \frac {1-s} 2 = \frac {1+s} 2$ and therefore $\sup_n |x_n + y_n| \le \frac {1+s} 2 < 1$, i.e. $B(x,\frac {1-s} 2) \subset C$.
- $C$ is **unbounded**: it contains all sequences first $n$ terms of which equal to $\frac 1 2$ and the rest are zeros, the norms of these sequences are $\frac n 2$, i.e. are unbounded.
- $C$ is clearly **symmetric**.
- $C$ is **convex**: if $x = (x_n) \in C$, $y = (y_n) \in C$ and $\sup_n |x_n| = u < 1$, $\sup_n |y_n| = v < 1$, then for any $\lambda \in (0,1)$ and $n \in \mathbb N$ we have: $|\lambda x_n + (1-\lambda) y_n| \le \lambda u + (1-\lambda) v \le \max(u, v)$, this implies $\sup_n |\lambda x_n + (1-\lambda) y_n| \le \max(u, v) < 1$ and $\lambda x + (1-\lambda) y \in C$.
- $C$ is **bounded in every direction**. Let $x = (x_n)$ and $x \ne 0$. Then $x_k \ne 0$ for some $k \in \mathbb N$ and we can take $\lambda_x = \frac 1 {|x_k|}$ because for any $\lambda$ such that $|\lambda| > \lambda_x$ we will have for the $k$-th term of $\lambda x$: $|\lambda x_k| = |\lambda| |x_k| > \frac 1 {|x_k|} |x_k| = 1$, therefore $\sup_n |\lambda x_n| > 1$ and $\lambda x \notin C$.